# JavaScript - Coverting invalid object into json object

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, object

I am currently making an ajax call to return data from an API. The return value is an object of an array. This format is an invalid object so I am having issues accessing the data that is being returned to me.

How can I convert this object into a valid json object so I can access the data that is being returned?

Here is an example of the data being returned:

```
data = { ["<p>Retail Websites has a profit value of $243,291. In the year 2020 we have seen a growth rate of about 2.3% </p>" ] }
```

I've tried using `dataType: json` in my ajax call but the result value is still the same.

Here is my ajax call using "dataType: json" :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: dataUrl,
    data: {
        "retailId": retailId, 
    },
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    error: function () {
        console.log("error")
    }
}).done(function (data) {
    console.log("retail data", data)
})
```

I am unable to access the data in this object. I am expecting to be able to access the data like a json object such as : `data[0]`. I am stuck on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Why does the API respond with invalid syntax?

Answer (score 1):

If your data is *set* as:

```
var data = { ["<p>Retail Websites has a profit value of $243,291. In the year 2020 we have seen a growth rate of about 2.3% </p>" ] }
```

Then the problem is the curly braces with no key. When you remove them, the array is correct. `data[0]` is equal to the string you expect.

If the result of your API call is the whole of `data = {...}` and you know that it is, then you can capture the string, remove the characters at the beginning and end that don't belong (everything outside the square brackets) and use `JSON.parse` to get your JSON data. There are several ways to remove the characters. If the text is always the case, you can use substrings, or if you need to be more flexible, you can use regular expressions.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed response. I am newer to coding so I apologize if my question seems redundant. Like you mentioned my issue is that I no key. I would like the array only but at the moment I am stuck with the curly braces. Like you mentioned I can remove the curly brace and then use `JSON.parse`. A method like `data.replace(/[{}]/g, '')` is possible to remove the curly? At the moment I was getting replace is not a function.

Comment: If your string is in `data` and you know, predictably, that the curly braces are the first and the last character, you can do this to remove them: `data.substring(1, data.length - 1)`. This will return the string `data` minus the first and last characters.

Comment: thank you for the example. I tried using `data.substring` as mentioned above but I continue getting `substring is not a function` I tried finding a solution on my own, and it states that substring only works on strings, since my string is in an object will substring still apply? Or is it something that I may be doing wrong on my own end. I tried doing `.done(function (data) { data.substring(1, data.length -1) `

Comment: I just noticed your response. Sorry. This may be far too late, but `substring` is a property of all strings. It is, in a way "inside" of strings, or, precisely, it's message you can send to any string. If another object *contains* a string, it will work on the part of the object that's a string. For example in: `o = {a: 1, b: [2, "w"]}`, `substring` will be in `o.b[1]` and you can call `o.b[1].substring()`. You cannot easily call functions in the middle of a string. You can do something similar with string interpolation (look it up), but I don't think that's what you need.